# Spring Quartz : Job does not fire

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz 2 and Spring 3.0

I want to use **SchedulerFactoryBean** but my Job is not getting fired.

Below is my XML file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="quartzScheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="schedulerName" value="PCLoaderScheduler"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My code is below:

```
@Component
public class PCSchedulerManager {

    @Autowired
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    public void scheduleJob(final Map<String, Object> parameters, Class inputClass) throws PCSchedulerException {

        try {
            long currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

            JobDetail job = JobBuilder
                            .newJob(inputClass)
                            .withIdentity(inputClass.getName() + currentTimeStamp)
                            .build();
            job.getJobDataMap().putAll(parameters);

            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                                .newTrigger()
                                .withIdentity(inputClass.getName() + currentTimeStamp)
                                .build();

            //Schedule a job with JobDetail and Trigger
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            throw new PCSchedulerException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer the **Job** I am trying to execute

```
public class LoaderJob implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Do your stuff here...");
    }

}
```

I know that the scheduler is getting started when the server starts. But It does not run my Job.

Also, If I use, the below statement instead of Autowiring the Spring Quartz scheduler, then the job is getting fired successfully

```
scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.start();
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz 2 and Spring 3.0 are incompatible. Updated Spring to 3.1. Now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to inject dependencies into the job? Then implement [QuartzJobBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/QuartzJobBean.html)

and override executeInternal() method.

Also please check If you are getting any exception while job execution.

Comment: No. It didn't work. Also, I remember that 'Job' used to work. But I am making some small mistake. Don't know what.

Comment: hi did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

First, go ahead and add something like this to your configuration xml file. Notice how you can change the repeatInterval and startDelay properties. Alternatively, you can use cron expressions as well. Read about them from [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm).

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
      <property name="triggers">
         <list>             
            <ref bean="cronTrgTest" />
         </list>
      </property>
   </bean>

    <bean id="cronTrgTest" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="testJob" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
        <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
    </bean>   

   <bean id="testJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
      <property name="targetObject" ref="cronTest" />
      <property name="targetMethod" value="test" />
   </bean>   

   <bean id="cronTest" class="com.mustafaergin.ws.cron.CronTest">
   </bean>
```

Then implement the target POJO and you are done.

```
public class CronTest {

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("TEST");
    }

}
```

You can find the original article I wrote a while ago [here](http://www.mustafaergin.com/java-cron-job/).

Comment: Thanks for your pointers about providing an answer. I included the critical parts in the answer.